# server side response in twig page for button

Tags: javascript, symfony, button, twig

I want to get a server side response for a button in a twig page.
As a example - there will be 2 button in the page ----

**ON/OFF**

When the page load it should check from server (check from elasticsearch database) whether it returns True or false, for both button.

So for instanse we say that for ON button it return "True" it should change it color to green, like ----

```
$(this).addClass('btn-success');
$(this).removeClass('btn-primary');
```

The main purpose is to check what's the current status, when the page load.

So this is not a on-click function, because it show show the status when the page is loaded.

I believe there will be some simple solution to solve this problem.

Do anyone knows how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has actually nothing to do with Symfony. All you need to do is send an **ajax** request to the server side script (controller) to get the status of the server. like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //send the request with empty data to the server to check the status
   $.post('/url/to/action', {}, function(msg){
     // we return a response like {status: 'on'} to the client if the search is on
     if (msg.status == 'on'){
       $('#your-button').addClass('success');
     }
     // else it is disabled
     else
       $('#your-button').addClass('primary');
   });
});
```

---

the above is your client side code, now to integrate it with your symfony app, `/url/to/action` must point to some controller action in your symfony app that returns the status, a sample implementation would be like this:

```
//in your controller, /url/to/action must lead to getStatusAction in your routing
public function getStatusAction(Request $request){
    if($this->isElasticEnabled())
      return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse(array('status' => 'on'));
      else 
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse(array('status' => 'off'));
}
```